# Did Cantor coin the terms countable and uncountable? If not, who did?

Tags: set-theory

I just assumed that he did since we owe the proof that $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable to him, but a search of my favorite source for answering such questions -- https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Miller/mathword/ -- doesn't even mention uncountable.

Comment: I suspect, without documentable back-up, that this notion had indeed not settled out of the whole set-theory tumult until probably Fraenkel's time. Our hindsight on these ideas is very misleading, as far as I can tell from my (amateurish, barely German-math-literate) reading of those old sources.

Comment: @njuffa - wow! Thank you seems very lame but it's all I got. I'll just get out of the way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Georg Cantor published a 47-page booklet, "Grundlagen einer allgemeinen Mannigfaltigkeitslehre," Leipzig: Teubner 1883. The title translates to "Foundations of a general set theory" and various English translations show that he refers to countable and uncountable sets in it. I am unable to find a scan of the German original online. *Mannigfaltigkeit* (literally translated: manifold) was Cantor's term for a set, the modern German term for which is *Menge*.

The material that comprises this monograph appears to also have been published (in somewhat different form) in various individual publications, one of which is

G. Cantor, "Ueber unendliche, lineare Punktmannichfaltigkeiten", *Mathematische Annalen*, Vol. 21, 1883, pp. 52-58 ([scan online](https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN235181684_0021?tify=%7B%22pages%22:%5B57%5D,%22panX%22:0.582,%22panY%22:0.359,%22view%22:%22info%22,%22zoom%22:0.767%7D)). As far as I understand, Cantor's concept of a point set is a subset of the real line. Note that the title uses a spelling variant of *Mannigfaltigkeit* suggested by Northern German pronunciation. On page 54 of this publication we find:

> Da nämlich alle Bestandtheile der rechten Seite abzählbar sind und die *Anzahl* dieser Bestandtheile eine *abzählbar unendliche* ist, so folgt
> daraus die Abzählbarkeit von $P'$ und nach Th. II diejenige von $P$. [...]

> Theorem V. *Jede Punktmenge $P$ zweiter Gattung, für welche $P^{(\alpha)}$ abzählbar, ist selbst abzählbar.* [...]

> *Ist $P$ eine nicht abzählbare Punktmenge, so ist auch $P^{(\alpha)}$ nicht abzählbar, sowohl wenn $\alpha$ eine endliche ganze Zahl, wie auch wenn es eines der Unendlichkeitssymbole ist.*

My translation: Since all components of the right-hand side are countable and the *number* of these components is *countably infinite*, it follows the countability of $P'$ and according to theorem II that of $P$. [...] Theorem V. *Every point set $P$ of the second class, for which $P^{(\alpha)}$ is countable, is itself countable.* [...] *If $P$ is an uncountable point set, then $P^{(\alpha)}$ is also uncountable, both when $\alpha$ is a finite integer and when it is one of the infinity symbols.*

Comment: a literal translation of "nicht abzählbar" would be "not countable", right?

Comment: @MichaelBächtold Correct. In my experience, use of *überabzählbar* ("more than can be counted") predominates in modern German usage in this context.

Comment: @njuffa. This is great.